# Get All Connected Users (Laravel 5)

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

How to display all connected users in my home?

Answer (score 7):

*This is a very basic, but hopefully an efective way to detect both `Guest` and `Registered` users on your Laravel5 application.*

**Step 1**

Open the file `config/session.php` and change the driver to database.

**Step 2**

We need to create the sessions table, so use the following artisan command `php artisan session:table` to generate the migration file.

**Step 3**

On this newly generated migration, you need to add a new `user_id` column, this is so we can relate the session to a user, if that user is logged in of course.

Open the file `migrations/xxxx_xx_xx_xxxxxx_create_session_table.php` and add the following inside the Schema::create:

`$t->integer('user_id')->nullable();`

Here is how the full migration should look:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSessionTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function($t) 
        {
            $t->string('id')->unique();
            $t->text('payload');
            $t->integer('last_activity');
            $t->integer('user_id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('sessions');
    }

}
```

**Step 4**

Run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan migrate`.

*Note: If you don't have Composer installed globally, just use `php composer.phar dump-autoload`.*

**Step 5**

Save the Eloquent Model somewhere on your application as `Session.php`.

*Note: The recommended place to save this is on the app directory.*

**Step 6**

Now you just need to know how to use it.

.
.
.

**Usage**

Place the following `Session::updateCurrent();` somewhere on your code, as this will make sure that the session entry for the current user get's updated, just an example, you can place it on your app/routes.php file.

Get all users (Guests + Registered)

`$all = Session::all();`

If you need to check all users online for a certain period, like 10 minutes, you need to call the `activity(:limit)` method, like so:

`$all = Session::activity(10)->get();`

Note: This method can be used in combination with the guests() and/or registered() methods.

Guest Users

Grab all

```
$guests = Session::guests()->get();
Get the # of Guest users

$total = Session::guests()->count();
```

Registered Users

Grab all

```
$registered = Session::registered()->get();

foreach ($registered as $online) {
    // You can retrieve the user information using something like:
    var_dump($online->user->email);
}
```

Get the # of Registered users

`$total = Session::registered()->count();`

**Eloquent model:**

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\Facades\Sentinel;

class Session extends Model 
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $table = 'sessions';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * Returns the user that belongs to this entry.
     *
     * @return \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser');
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the users within the given activity.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @param  int  $limit
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeActivity($query, $limit = 10)
    {
        $lastActivity = strtotime(Carbon::now()->subMinutes($limit));

        return $query->where('last_activity', '>=', $lastActivity);
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the guest users.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeGuests(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->whereNull('user_id');
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the registered users.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeRegistered(Builder $query)
    {
        return $query->whereNotNull('user_id')->with('user');
    }

    /**
     * Updates the session of the current user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function scopeUpdateCurrent(Builder $query)
    {
        $user = Sentinel::check();

        return $query->where('id', Session::getId())->update([
            'user_id' => $user ? $user->id : null
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Alternatively you can try [this](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker).**

Comment: Hello , thank you for your answer ,

in the **step1** how i can change that ??

Comment: `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database')` ... check out [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#database-sessions)

Comment: I can't understand the **step5** and **step6** !!

Comment: i have this exeption in my terminal before starting the server

 `[ErrorException]
 call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'I
 lluminate\Session\Store' does not have a method 'updateCurrent'`

Comment: did you import Eloquent model ? maybe should be `scopeUpdateCurrent` ... sorry can't check it right now...

Comment: Yes, i try it with `scopeUpdateCurrent` too , but it dosen't work

Comment: Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Sir , are u here , i want to ask you about this link https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker ?

Comment: I didn't use it, but seems like a legit github project. If you got problems with module, maybe it would be more effective to ask an author.

Comment: any solution for that ? i want to get all connected users to pass to my step2 socket.io ...

Comment: Any news on this? i've hit the same wall : (call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Session\Store' does not have a method 'updateCurrent'