# Laravel 5 Database Sessions (Laravel 5.0)

Tags: php, laravel, session, eloquent

I am attempting to update my application so that sessions are handled via the database instead of flat files, so that I can track which users are currently logged in and in order to do so have been using the following resources to help:

[Get All Connected Users (Laravel 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32666052/get-all-connected-users-laravel-5)

https://gist.github.com/brunogaspar/494903b3dd16321a12d1

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#configuration

However for some reason, despite following each step I just get the following error:

```
ErrorException in Manager.php line 139:

call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Session\Store' does not have a method 'updateCurrent'
```

Can anybody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples you need to create `Session` Model and include it with `use` directive:

```
use App\Session;
```

Then you can call `Session::updateCurrent();` as described.

Comment: Hey thanks, yeah I see, my main problem is that I need to install Sentinel, unfortuantly im having issues with that also right now. I keep getting:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\src\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider::class' not found

despite the file existing, im quite confused

Answer (score 0):

So i believe I've figured it out, I needed to install sentinel first, which I've done and I no longer get the errors, however I still see no sessions being stored in the database :(

Regards,